# Fix file associations in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, ubuntu-18.04

How do you fix the file extension associations with LibreOffice Calc? I have a CSV-like file with a `*.dsv` file extension. Ubuntu has that file type set as a CSV document. When I explicitly try to open it with LibreOffice Calc, LibreOffice insists on opening it in Writer. E.g., I can run the command:

```bsh
soffice --calc ./mydata.dsv
```

and LibreOffice will force it to open in Writer rather than Calc. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

- Open Ubuntu's file manager ("Files", i.e., Dolphin, Nautilus, etc.).
- [Right-click on a *.dsv* file and select *Properties*.](https://websiteforstudents.com/open-files-with-default-apps-in-ubuntu-17-10-18-04/)
- On the *Open With* tab, find *Calc*, and select it.
- Click on *Set as default*.

If that doesn't work, then you can [create a new MIME](https://coderwall.com/p/qjda2q/create-new-mime-type-and-assign-an-icon-to-it-in-ubuntu) type, or [create a *.desktop* file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16580/where-are-file-associations-stored) to set file association.

*N.B.* This question pretty much duplicates [one in *Ask Ubuntu*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289337/how-can-i-change-file-association-globally).

Comment: I already tried that. I assigned `*.dsv` to the `text/csv` MIME type.

Comment: The command tries launching the file with Calc but LibreOffice is opening it in Writer instead. `*.csv` files open fine.

Comment: "I tried that": which one of the three suggestions did you try? Why did you not try the other two methods?